# Get parameter type name of generic base repository

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-data-jpa

I am not sure if even possible, but my question is: Is there a way to get the class name of the generic parameter inside a base repository implementation.
This is my base interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AclBaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T>, CrudRepository<T, Long> {
    List<T> findAllWithAcl(Predicate predicate);
    Page<T> findAllWithAcl(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And this is my implementation

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class AclBaseRepositoryImpl<T extends BaseEntity> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, Long> implements AclBaseRepository<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AclBaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, Long> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAllWithAcl(Predicate predicate) {
        return findAll(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAllWithAcl(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends AclBaseRepository<Account> {
}
```

The basic idea was: Have a common base repository for all "implemented" repositories with a few new methods (e.g. findAllWithAcl). Those new methods would inject a additional predicate (QueryDsl) into the defined query predicate which basically filters the rows according to some ACL tables. For that query i would need the class name of the entity being loaded. I would be fine with passing the class name as a parameter to the constructor, but since i use this base repository as a new repositoryBaseClass (e.g. `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = AclBaseRepositoryImpl.class)`) and my repositories are interfaces, i have no control over the parameters.
Is this possible? Is there another/better way to do this without needing to repeat the same code multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information from the `JpaEntityInformation` instance you get provided in the constructor. 
Since it implements [`JpaEntityMetadata`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaEntityMetadata.java) and [`EntityMetadata`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/EntityMetadata.java) you have access to the entity name via `getEntityName()` and to the domain class via `getJavaType()`.

Also, since `AclBaseRepositoryImpl` inherits from [`QuerydslJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaRepository.java) which inherits from [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) you can simply call `getDomainClass`.

Comment: Thank you. So nice and simple!